# Android Keystore returns TrustedCertificateEntry instead PrivateKeyEntry

Tags: android, keystore, classcastexception, android-keystore

I have the following `setKey()`:

```
try {
            if(keyPair!=null) {
                privateKeyResult = (RSAKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
                certificate = generateCertificate(keyPair, before, after);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateEncodingException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException | SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Error in preparing for insertion to keystore", e);
            sendLogs(e);
        }

        try {
            if(keyStore!=null) {
                keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, (Key) privateKeyResult, null, new Certificate[]{certificate});
            }
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            logger.error("Error in insertion to keystore", e);
            sendLogs(e);
        }
```

and the following getKey():

```
try {
                privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);

            if (privateKeyEntry == null) {
                if (createKeyIfNotExists) {
                    logger.info("key is null, will attempt to create a new one");
                    setKey(alias,null);
                    //get the newly create key
                    privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
                }
            } else {
                //logger.debug("key was found");
                privateKey = (RSAKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
                return privateKey;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableEntryException | KeyStoreException | NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error("Exception getting key from keystore", e);
            sendLogs(e);
        }
```

while it works on 99.98% of the devices, still, on some of them (mostly OnePlus) I've got the following exception:

```
java.security.KeyStore$TrustedCertificateEntry cannot be cast to java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry
```

in the line `privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);` while trying to get the `PrivateKeyEntry`. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue to make sure that application works on 100% devices? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am having the exact same situation;  I am calling KeyStore#setEntry(…) with a KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry() but one line later when I call KeyStore#getEntry() on the exact same alias it is now 'magically transformed' into a TrustedCertificateKey and the private-key data is lost (I'm about to test on a second platform device)

Answer (score 0):

May be in the OnePlus the `getEntry` is only returning the `Certificate` of the Key Pair entry.

You could do something like this to cast it accordingly:

```
KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry("ALIAS", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("PASSWORD".toCharArray()));
if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
    System.out.println("Private Key...");
else if (entry instanceof KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry)
    System.out.println("Trusted Certificate...");
else if (entry instanceof KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)
    System.out.println("Secret Key...");
```

Comment: Yes, that would helpful to avoid Class Cast Exception, but the main question remains - why would KeyStore return wrong entry type ?